# TypeError: data.map is not a function, even though the data is an array (i think)

Tags: json, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

Im using Django rest to send data to react:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "Dewalian",
    "question": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "how to cook?"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "how to exercise?"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "Edward",
    "question": []
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "username": "Jeremy",
    "question": []
}
]
```

and then fetch it using a custom hook from a video tutorial:

```
import useFetch from "./UseFetch";
import DataList from "./DataList";

const MainContent = () => {
    const {data: question, isPending, error} = useFetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/");

return ( 
    <div className="main-content">
        {error && <div>{error}</div>}
        {isPending && <div>Loading...</div>}
        {question && <DataList data={question} />}
    </div>
      );
 };

export default MainContent;
```

finally i map it on another component:

```
const DataList = (data) => {
return ( 
      <div>
         {data.map(user => (
            <div key={user.id}>
                <p>{user.username}</p>
            </div>
         ))}
      </div>
      );
 }

 export default DataList;
```

but i get "TypeError: data.map is not a function". Im pretty sure the problem is on the json, but i dont know what's wrong. so, what's wrong and how to fix this? thanks.

**EDIT**

this is the useFetch custom hooks (just a normal fetch with a useEffect):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortCont = new AbortController();

        fetch(url)
        .then(res => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw Error ("Couldn't fetch data from that resource.")
            };
            return res.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            setData(data);
            setIsPending(false);
            setError(null);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if (err.name === "AbortError") {
                console.log("fetch aborted.")
            } else {
                setIsPending(false);
                setError(err.message);
            };
        });

        return () => abortCont.abort();
    }, [url]);

    return {data, isPending, error};
};

export default useFetch;
```

and the api/user:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def user_all(request):
    model_data = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(model_data, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I think it will easy if you debug it by putting a breakpoint on useFetch line to see what is the returned values.

Comment: the returned values are exactly the same as the json data above (the other two is basically check for "loading" and error value)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can not comment on the post, I will edit this one later.

Would you mind sharing the code for your custom hook ?
Even better if you share the /api/user/ view code.

```
const data = useFetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/");
console.log(data)
```

You will view it in google developer tools -> console.
also you should be able to view the request directly from network -> click on the response from the custom url -> find response in the options.

Also you can view the response using print() in the backend side,

Or you can directly send a request using httpie or postman to your api using a valid token (

- if your api uses isAuthenticated permission then you need to copy a user token from the backend
- if your api uses AllowAny, then you do not need an access token from your backend you can fetch the data directly from any request.
- if your api uses isAdmin then you need the admin access token.
- And so on. depend on your permission.

**[EDIT]**
Looks like the problem in your custom hook, in the fetch statement,
it is returning res.json()
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

```
const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortCont = new AbortController();
fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET', // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  setData(data);
 setIsPending(false);
  setError(null);
})
.catch((error) => {
  if (err.name === "AbortError") {
                console.log("fetch aborted.")
            } else {
                setIsPending(false);
                setError(err.message);
            };
});

        return () => abortCont.abort();
    }, [url]);

    return {data, isPending, error};
};

export default useFetch;
```

then you can destructure your fetched data like this

```
const { data, isPending, error } = useFetch(url);
```

now data is an array and has data.questions, data.username

in your map fuction you can use it like this

```
{data.map(i => {
// {i.id}
// {i.question}
// {i.username} 
})
}
```

Comment: edited, im pretty sure this has nothing to do with the custom hook. I dont really know about token that you're talking tho, is it like csrf token on django?

Comment: You are probably right, your issue must be in destructuring the response would you mind sharing the response. It is not CSRF token it is another story, In REST APIs there are access tokens that prevent unauthorized users to fetch data from your API, You can customize the permission access using  permission_classes attributes usually it is a tuple or list, inside it you add the permission classes to learn more visit this link:  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: this is the [response](https://imgur.com/a/OBTMBnz)

Comment: I edit my answer, please check it and let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, but turns out i forgot to put { } on the argument of DataList component :')

Comment: also a tip, if you want to send a code/snippet; paste it first, select/block all the code/snippet, and then ctrl + k

Comment: glad to help <3 , but, I am still sure, you are not error validating, based on the response you sent me, you are only returning the data on the first then. To get what I am talking about, console.log(data,isPending,Error) with your hook without my edit, then console.log() with my edit

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to put {} on the argument:

```
const DataList = ({data}) => {
return ( 
      <div>
         {data.map(user => (
            <div key={user.id}>
                <p>{user.username}</p>
            </div>
         ))}
      </div>
      );
 }

 export default DataList;
```